# Evaluating the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n^{k}}}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, asymptotics

> Determine, with proof, the value of the limit $L = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{2^{n^{k}}}{n!}$ where $k=1.1.$

I think it's infinite because $\frac{2^{n^k}}{n!}\ge (\frac{2^{n^{0.1}}}{n})^n=(2^{n^{0.1}-\log n})^n\to \infty.$

Comment: Sometimes our intuition leads us astray, which is fine.... Hint: $n! \le n^n$ and $\frac{2^{n^{1.1}}}{n^n} = \big( \frac{2^{n^{0.1}}}n \big)^n$.

Comment: Write down what a(n+1) / a(n) is. For large n it becomes large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I'm pretty sure the limit with $k=1.1$ should evaluate to $0$"  Well, no ...

Let $a_n= \dfrac{2^{n^{1.1}}}{n!}.$ Then

$$\tag1 \ln a_n = n^{1.1}\ln 2- \ln n! \ge n^{1.1}\ln 2- n\ln n = n(n^{.1}\ln 2-\ln n).$$

Since $n^{.1}\ln 2-\ln n \to \infty,$ we see $(1)\to \infty.$ It follows that $a_n\to \infty.$

Answer (score 2):

Define $a_n:=\frac{2^{n^k}}{n!}$. I will show that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\left\{\begin{matrix} \infty &\text{if} & k>1\\
0 & \text{if} & k\leq 1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

- If $k>1$, then by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
  $$(n+1)^k-n^k=n^k\Big(\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^k-1\big)\geq n^k\frac{k}{n}=n^{k-1}k$$
  Hence
  $$ a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{2^{n^k}}{n!}2^{(n+1)^k-n^k}=\frac{2^{(n+1)^k-n^k}}{n+1}a_n\geq \frac{(2^k)^{n^{k-1}}}{n+1}a_n$$
  Recall that for any $a>1$ and $\beta>0$
  $$\frac{x+1}{{a}^{x^\beta}}=\frac{\big(x^{\beta}\big)^{\tfrac{1}{\beta}}+1}{{a}^{x^\beta}}\stackrel{y=x^{\beta}}{=}\frac{y^{1/\beta}+1}{a^y}\xrightarrow{y\rightarrow\infty}0$$
  Thus, for $k>1$, there is $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$
  $a_{n+1}>2a_n$. This means that
  $$a_{n+n_0}\geq 2^n a_{n_0}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$$
- For $k\leq 1$, $n^k\leq n$ and so,
  $$\frac{2^{n^k}}{n!}\leq \frac{2^n}{n!}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

Answer (score 0):

By ratio test, for any $k>1$

$$\dfrac{2^{(n+1)^{k}}}{(n+1)!}\dfrac{n!}{2^{n^{k}}}=\frac{2^{(n+1)^{k}-n^k}}{n+1}\ge \frac{2^{kn^{k-1}}}{n+1}\to \infty$$